# SonarQube Scanner execution fails: java can't be indexed twice

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am working with:

- sonarqube 7.3
- scanner 3.2.0.1227

I have a Gradle multi module

```
sonarqube-03
   sonarqube-03-domain
   sonarqube-03-repository
   sonarqube-03-repository-impl
```

I have just **one** `sonar-project.properties` file located in the root project `sonarqube-03` with the following content:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=manolito-labs:sonarqube-03
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=sonarqube-03
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# This property is optional if sonar.modules is set.
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=src

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#Manolito
sonar.exclusions=build/**,\
                 bin/**,\
                 gradle/**,\
                 gradlew,\
                 gradlew.bat,\
                 *.gradle
sonar.java.binaries=.

#Multi-Module
sonar.modules=sonarqube-03-domain,\
              sonarqube-03-repository,\
              sonarqube-03-repository-impl

# Properties can obviously be overriden for
# each module - just prefix them with the module ID
sonarqube-03-domain.sonar.projectName=Module Sonarqube 03 Domain
sonarqube-03-repository.sonar.projectName=Module Sonarqube 03 Repository
sonarqube-03-repository-impl.sonar.projectName=Module Sonarqube 03 Repository Impl
```

When I execute on Mac: `$SONARQUBE_SCANNER/bin/sonar-scanner`

I got in the final of the all the output:

```
...
INFO: Source paths: src
INFO: Test paths: src
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=162ms
INFO: Index files
INFO: Excluded sources:
INFO:   build/**
INFO:   bin/**
INFO:   gradle/**
INFO:   gradlew
INFO:   gradlew.bat
INFO:   *.gradle
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 11.684s
INFO: Final Memory: 11M/167M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: File sonarqube-03-repository/src/main/java/com/manuel/jordan/repository/PersonRepository.java can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

If I execute with the debug mode (`$SONARQUBE_SCANNER/bin/sonar-scanner -X`)

I got:

```
...
13:31:07.362 INFO: Source paths: src
13:31:07.363 INFO: Test paths: src
13:31:07.363 INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
13:31:07.370 INFO: Load server rules
13:31:07.480 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=109ms
13:31:07.510 INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=140ms
13:31:07.663 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Python were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.py : **/*.py
13:31:07.663 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language CSS were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.css : **/*.css,**/*.less,**/*.scss
13:31:07.664 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Go were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.go : **/*.go
13:31:07.664 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Kotlin were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.kotlin : **/*.kt
13:31:07.664 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js,**/*.jsx,**/*.vue
13:31:07.664 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C# were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cs : **/*.cs
13:31:07.664 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
13:31:07.665 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Flex were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.flex : **/*.as
13:31:07.665 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language XML were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.xml : **/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.xsl
13:31:07.665 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language PHP were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.php : **/*.php,**/*.php3,**/*.php4,**/*.php5,**/*.phtml,**/*.inc
13:31:07.666 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language TypeScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.ts : **/*.ts,**/*.tsx
13:31:07.680 INFO: Index files
13:31:07.683 INFO: Excluded sources:
13:31:07.684 INFO:   build/**
13:31:07.684 INFO:   bin/**
13:31:07.684 INFO:   gradle/**
13:31:07.684 INFO:   gradlew
13:31:07.684 INFO:   gradlew.bat
13:31:07.684 INFO:   *.gradle
13:31:07.702 DEBUG: 'src/main/java/com/manuel/jordan/repository/PersonRepository.java' indexed with language 'java'
13:31:07.779 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:31:07.779 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
13:31:07.779 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:31:07.779 INFO: Total time: 3.231s
13:31:07.846 INFO: Final Memory: 11M/167M
13:31:07.846 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:31:07.846 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
13:31:07.846 ERROR: File sonarqube-03-repository/src/main/java/com/manuel/jordan/repository/PersonRepository.java can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files
```

For both outputs the problem is:

```
ERROR: File 
sonarqube-03-repository
/src/main/java
/com/manuel/jordan/repository/PersonRepository.java 
can't be indexed twice. 
Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files
```

Thus, what is missing in my current configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You incorrectly configured `sources` and `tests`:

```
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=src
```

They direct to the same directory. You can even read in the log:

```
Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files
```

You should specify `sonar.tests` only when tests classes are not in `src` directory.

---

If you still want to scan tests, then you have two options:

1. Keep tests together with sources.
2. Create a new project which store tests in `src` directory. This project should depend on original sources.

---

Finally, the feature which you need is unsupported right now, but there is a [feature request](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/allow-enabling-sonar-rules-for-test-sources/3379/2?u=agabrys) ([MMF-1451](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1451)) - feel free to watch and vote.

Comment: I see. I have same result if for both properties have the same value: a `.` (dot). Even if you are correct. How apply Sonar for `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` in peace? I want apply Sonar to my Test and Utility Test classes. Thanks

Comment: I've extended the answer.

Comment: Could you share a valid configuration about `Sonarquebe` applied for a multimodule project in Gradle? Where some modules have dependencies with others and where the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` must be scanned.

Comment: I think you can just set `sonar.sources=src/main/java,src/test/java` and make `sonar.tests` empty (`sonar.tests=`). The feature which you need is unsupported right now, but there is a [feature request](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/allow-enabling-sonar-rules-for-test-sources/3379/2?u=agabrys) ([MMF-1451](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1451)) - feel free to vote.

Comment: Thanks for the two links. Seems this software needs add its powerful support for testing too.

Comment: >>You should specify sonar.tests only when tests classes are not in src directory.

That's not what the doc says though. In this [example](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/project-administration/analysis-scope/#example-2), they have this:
# Define the same root directory for sources and tests
sonar.sources = src/
sonar.tests = src/