# How to solve File can’t be indexed twice error in Run Code Analysis task TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I am using SonarQube version 7.4 and TFS build task Run Code Analysis version 4

I am getting an error **File can’t be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files**

Below is my configuration for Prepare analysis on SonarQube task step

```
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.sources=(Build.SourcesDirectory)
sonar.inclusions=Code/**
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=**/*.trx
sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=**/*.coveragexml
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=(Build.SourcesDirectory)
sonar.cfamily.threads=6
sonar.cfamily.cppunit.reportsPath=**/result.xml
sonar.branch.name=(Build.SourceBranchName) sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\dependency-check-report.xml
sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\dependency-check-report.html
```

Also below is my project folder structure

```
Client
    Code
    Lib
    Package
    Research
    Runners
    Tools
```

I want to scan only Code folder, Please help me.

Comment: Have you specify the path of your tests classes, like sonar.tests=...?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633708/sonarqube-scanner-execution-fails-java-cant-be-indexed-twice And according the document https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/FAQ, you should check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for **source** and **test files** instead of only the source files.

Comment: Actually I have removed sonar.sources instaed added sonar.inclusions and sonar.exclusions after this it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to solve File can’t be indexed twice error in Run Code Analysis task TFS?

According to your configuration for Prepare analysis on SonarQube task step, it seems that you have not configured the source and test files correctly.

Based on the [FAQ on SonarOpenCommunity](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/FAQ), we could to know:

> Q: ERROR: Caused by: File [...] can't be indexed twice.
>
> A: In case of below error **you have to verify your exclusion/inclusion
>   properties. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce
>   disjoint sets for source and test files**

So, to resolve this issue, we need to check the **inclusion/exclusion** patterns produce
disjoint sets for **source and test files**.

@Naveen Kumar`s solution:

Removed sonar.sources instaed added sonar.inclusions and sonar.exclusions resolved his issue.

Comment: but still I am confused why it worked after removing sonar.sources

Comment: @NaveenKumar, It seems you have specify the `sonar.sources` and `sonar.inclusions`, it will index the files twice. You can check the similar issue from this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633708/sonarqube-scanner-execution-fails-java-cant-be-indexed-twice

Comment: thanks I got your point but before I was just trying with the sonar.sources=(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Code, but it failed then I included sonar.inclusions